# WPF Text Formatting in GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to apply a format (align text, format for the currency 0000.00) to the columns in the GridViewColumn.

```
 <GridViewColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Name}"/>
```

The idea is the following one: In the columns (GridViewColumn) the text that our could apply a format to him (Aligners on the left, right, center, justify, etc.).

In the following code they can see the different attempts without obtaining any result

The code is as follows:

```
 <Window x:Class="ListViewTest.Test0.ListViewTest"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Title="Empty ListView Grid" Height="216" Width="435" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="False">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="CustomersDS" Source="C:\data.xml"/>
        <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>



    <ListView Margin="0,0,0,50" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CustomerTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomersDS}, XPath=/Customers/Customer}">
        <ListView.View>
            <!--ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}"-->
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Width="80" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=Code}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Country}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=money}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>


</Window>
```

XML

```
     <Customers>
  <Customer>
 <Code>1234</Code>
 <Name>EPI</Name>
 <Country>Sesame Street</Country>
<money> 98.00</money>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
 <Code>3234</Code>
 <Name>Paul</Name>
 <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
<money> 8.70</money>
  </Customer>
 <Customer>
 <Code>3344</Code>
 <Name>Juan</Name>
 <Country>Spain</Country>
<money> 785.5</money>
  </Customer>
 <Customer>
 <Code>4321</Code>
 <Name>Dodo</Name>
 <Country>Venezuela</Country>
<money> 150.02</money>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand. Anyone else?

Comment: I explain better? Thanks for helping

Comment: Why is this question a community wiki?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is how I did something similar (format and align a currency column):

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Amount">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I also added this style:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

If you aren't using .NET 3.5 SP1, you'll need to use a converter instead of the StringFormat.

Comment: You have to do that for every single column?

Comment: @Stylzs05 - yep. WPF for the win :(

Answer (score 2):

To have a stringformat for currency for example, you can use "StringFormat" which was introduced on the binding object in .net3.5 sp1 I think.

```
Text="{Binding XPath=Code, StringFormat=0.000}"
```

Besides that, I must say I don't quite understand your question either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but can not get it to work.

Comment: Hmm indeed. Doesn't work here either. Seems like the XML you are reading already is a string, and the format function doesn't wsork there.

Other possibility: value converters: http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/value_converters_pg1.htm